# Trying to get the number of words line by line from a txt file

Tags: java

I'm trying to read create a basic class that reads a text file I made, and prints out the number of words on each specific line.

The output I want is each integer to be printed on a new line. For example, if the first line had 10 words, second had 23, third had 24, I want:

10

23

24

But for some reason my code is giving me

190

0

Which is the total number of words in the file and when it resets to 0. What am I doing wrong?

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class numWords {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    File file = new File("words.txt");

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
    int numWords = 0;

    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            numWords++; //counts number of words
            scanner.next(); //goes to the next word if available

        }
        System.out.println(numWords); //prints the number of words
        numWords = 0;  //resets it to 0
        scanner.nextLine(); //goes to the next line

    }
    scanner.close();

}
```

}

I have tried making an if statement saying if there aren't anymore lines, then I would use scanner.close();.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that scanner.next() will continue through line breaks. You'll want to get each line individually, then do the word count and output it.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class numWords {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    File file = new File("words.txt");

    Scanner filescanner = new Scanner(file);
    int numWords = 0;

    while (filescanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = filescanner.nextLine(); //pulls in next line
        Scanner linescanner = new Scanner(line); //create new scanner for just this line
        while (linescanner.hasNext()) {
            numWords++; //counts number of words
            linescanner.next(); //goes to the next word if available

        }
        System.out.println(numWords); //prints the number of words
        numWords = 0;  //resets it to 0
        linescanner.close();
    }
    filescanner.close();
}
```

Comment: It seems like I'm getting the right output, but I'm getting this error "Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
 at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1540)
 at javaFiles.numWords.main(numWords.java:27)"

Comment: Sorry...fixed the one line: String line = filescanner.nextLine()  instead of String line = scanner.nextLine(). It was a copy/paste fail :(

Comment: No worries, I already fixed that, it seems like it still wants to continue scanning when it shouldn't but I could be wrong. Any ideas why?

Comment: I don't see anything that would cause that. I'd try printing out each word to see where it's tripping.

Comment: For some reason my txt file had 2 blank lines, and somehow getting rid of them fixed my issues. Thank you for helping!

Comment: @D.R. you're causing `filescanner.nextLine()` to throw an exception because you're calling it twice inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative solution, using just three lines of code in the body of `main`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Files.lines(Paths.get("words.txt"))
            .map(String::trim)
            .forEach(line -> System.out.println(line.isEmpty()? 0 : line.split("\\s+").length));
}
```

Or, in Java 9:

```
private final Pattern NON_WHITESPACE = Pattern.compile("\\S+");

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Files.lines(Paths.get("words.txt"))
            .forEach(line -> System.out.println(NON_WHITESPACE.matcher(line).results().count()));
}
```

(Ideally, `Files.lines()` should be in a try-with-resources but I've left it out for brevity since this is the only statement in the `main()` method so the file will get closed when `main()` returns.)

Answer (score -1):

In your `while` loop, you could split the whole line (by spaces) into a `String array`, and then just count the number of entries.

```
String[] words;
     while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        words = Pattern.compile("\\s+").split(line);
        System.out.println(words.length);
     }
```

**Note:** I used a `BufferedReader`

Comment: You created new variables (such as line) and switched to a BufferedReader. You should include more code for a more complete answer.

Comment: This counts blank lines as one word.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException Fair enough - my answer wasn't well received as I copied/pasted an old version I had and modified slightly but there's an accepted answer already so no need for further updates here - but thanks :)